# Correct notation for tensor with values in a specific interval and a specific type

Tags: notation, tensors

I am writing because I do not know how to accurately describe, in math, the properties of the tensors I am working with.

I am working with a tensor $T$ resulting from reading a PNG image. The image have a height $H$, a width $W$ and channels $C$ (for PNG the channels are $C=3$). So the resulting tensor $T$ have a shape of $H \times W \times C$. Since the PNG image is stored as a set of unsigned integers, then, the values for each channel would vary from $[0, 255]$ (because it is coded with $8$ bits) and this interval would consist of natural numbers only (unsigned integers or positive integers).

**My question is: How to express that accurately in math?**

Before posting here I have been researching a bit. I know tensors can be represented with matrix notation or with multilinear map notation. So far my approaches to accurately describe this tensor $T$ are the following:

- Matrix notation: $T \in [0, 255]^{H \times W \times C}$ with $t_{h,w,c} \in \mathbb{N}$
- Multilinear map notation: $T : H \times W \times C$ with $t_{h,w,c} \in [0, 255] \in \mathbb{N}$

But I am not sure if they are correctly expressed since I am not a mathematician, so any suggestions, help, modifications or hints would be highly appreciated.